# Why is it necessary to trim before comparing string data?

Tags: el

There is a collection :

```
<c:set var = "tab" scope = "session" value = "${listIndicateurANN}" />
```

I loop it and make a test :

```
<c:forEach items="${tab}" var="obj" >
    <c:if test="${fn:trim(obj[12]) eq 'T'}">
```

Although the data `obj[12]` 's length is 1 ! So why ?

Comment: Is this the real code? You've a typo there which makes it to always evaluate true. Please copypaste the MCVE unmodified.

Comment: sorry , it s corrected now , I copied the exact code !

Comment: Most likely `obj[12]` is simply not a `java.lang.String`. To figure out what type exactly it is, print `${obj[12]['class'].name}`.

Comment: after displaying `${obj[12]['class'].name}` it gives `java.lang.Character` ; so how to make the test correctly ?

Comment: Compare with a char instead of a string, or convert char to string first as you did with fn:trim ;)

Comment: I dont know ! Are there different functions to make test if it is char or String ?

Comment: See the abovelinked dupe.